# How to produce Metrics/Statistics for API calls in spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and would like to produces statistics/metrics for my restful APIs. i have followed [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-api-metrics) link, he is explaining with "Spring Boot Acutator"..... I am not able to understand whether it is a good approach or not...
Can anyone tell me what is the correct way to produce statistics/metrics for APIs in Spring MVC?

Comment: The good thing about "Spring Boot Acutator" is that you can use it without doing so much by your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot creators also recommend an excellent [Metrics](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/) module from the [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/) project.
You can use it along with your Spring application.

Comment: @Demecki , Thank you , but my project is not spring boot application.. it is just spring mvc project.

Comment: @HareeshKumar AFAIK it doesn't matter. You can use Dropwizard Metrics anyway.